# Proof writing involving union and intersection : $(A \cup B = A \cap B) \implies ( A = B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Prove: $(A \cup B = A \cap B) \implies ( A = B)$**

Suppose $x \in A$, then $x ∈ A \cup B$. So then $x \in A \cap B$. Thus $x \in B$ and thus $A \subseteq B$

Suppose $x \in B$, then $x \in A \cup B$. So then $x \in A \cap B$. Thus $x \in A$ and thus $B \subseteq A$

Therefore, $A = B$

Is this correct? Another way to prove this? tips for a better proof writing?

Comment: It is correct and simple.

Comment: Is this also valid: Suppose  x ∈ A, then x ∈ A ∩ B. So then x ∈ A ⋃ B. Thus x ∈ B and thus A ⊆ B?

Comment: No, this way is not correct.

Comment: ohhhh i see! Thanks @Svetoslav

Comment: @Steve $x \in A \cup B \nRightarrow x \in B$

Comment: @gt6989b thanks makes so much sense now!

Comment: Does it make a difference if (A∪B=A∩B) switches to (A∩B = A∪B)? is my proof is still valid? @gt6989b

Comment: @Steve doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**An other way**

$$A\subset A\cup B=A\cap B\subset A $$
and

$$B\subset A\cup B= A\cap B\subset B.$$

Therefore
$$A=A\cup B=A\cap B=B.$$

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof by contradiction, $A\neq B$, then either:

1. $\exists x: x\in A\wedge  x \notin B$
2. $\exists x: x\in B\wedge  x \notin A$

Let's look at 1 (2 is symmetrical). From 1 $\Rightarrow x \notin A\cap B$ which means (from $A \cap  B = A\cup  B$ assumption) $x \notin A\cup B$ which is a contradiction (with $A\cup B = \left \{ x: x \in A \vee x \in B \right \}$).