# Is my proof for $A\cup B=A\cap B\iff A=B$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I would appreciate it if you could let me know whether my proof is correct. If not, I was hoping you could guide me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

---

For the forward arrow: (Assume $A\cup B=A\cap B$)

> ($A\subset B$) Let $x\in A$. Then, $x\in A\cup B\rightarrow x\in A\cap B\rightarrow x\in A \land x\in B\rightarrow x\in B.$ Thus, $A\subset B$.
>
> ($B\subset A$) Similarly, let $x\in B$. Then, $x\in A\cup B\rightarrow x\in A\cap B\rightarrow x\in A \land x\in B\rightarrow x\in A.$ Thus, $B\subset A$.
>
> $A\subset B \land B\subset A \iff A=B$

For the backward arrow: (Assume $A=B$)

> Assume $A=B$. Then, $\ A\cup B= A\cup A= A= A\cap A= A\cap B$.

---

Comment: Perfect! Good job.

Comment: Excellent proof.

Comment: You could simplify the forward direction by noting that $A \cup B \supset A \supset A \cap B$ hence $A = A \cap B$ and similarly for $B$ hence $A=B$.

Comment: Thank you very much all!

Comment: Note that $A\cup B=A\cap B\iff (A\cup B) - (A \cap B) = \emptyset$, See symmetric difference operator ${\displaystyle A\,\triangle \,B}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: Also check this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451247/proof-writing-involving-union-and-intersection-a-cup-b-a-cap-b-implies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine, I think though that there is no need to introduce any $x$.

Since $\begin{cases} A\subset (A\cup B)\\(A\cap B)\subset A\end{cases}\quad$ then $A\cup B=(A\cup B)\cup A=(A\cap B)\cup A=A$

Since $\begin{cases} B\subset (A\cup B)\\(A\cap B)\subset B\end{cases}\quad$ then $A\cup B=(A\cup B)\cup B=(A\cap B)\cup B=B$

Thus $A=B$

Comment: Obviously this is correct from a technical perspective, but I think it's quite useful pedagogically to start doing these basic set proofs by evaluating memberships in the fashion as the original poster did. The "algebra lawyering" approach you demonstrated can seem mysterious to students and make it seem as though a lexicon of set equations, rather than thought, is the correct way to proceed. (Again, this is *not* a criticism of your method -- I'm just saying that as a teacher, I'd probably lead students toward the $x \in \dots \implies x \in \dots$ approach.)